# R : Create new column with the difference between values from the same column where one of them match a condition

Tags: r, dplyr, powerbi

I have a data frame with the columns: Slot, Period, SortNumber and Value. 
Actually, this data frame was created reading data from some access databases and I do some work on it comparing string, etc... So, I use RODBC and stringr packages as well. This part of the code works perfectly in R and Power BI, so, I did not reproduce here. 
This is an example of my final data frame:

```
dfAccess <- data.frame(Slot = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X1", "X3","X1", "X2", "X3", "X2", "X3"), 
                       Period = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2), 
                       SortNumber = c(1, 1, 1, 1,1,2,2,2,2,2), 
                       Value = c(9,5,7,9,5,6,4,8,2,1))
```

This data frame does not have Slot X2 for Period 2 in SortNumber 1 neither Slot X1 for Period 2 in SortNumber 2 (it can missed any row). Visually, it means:

```
Slot     Period    SortNumber    Value    
=======================================
X1         1          1           9    
X2         1          1           5    
X3         1          1           7    
X1         2          1           9   
X3         2          1           5    
X1         1          2           6    
X2         1          2           4    
X3         1          2           8    
X2         2          2           2    
X3         2          2           1
```

I want to create a new column (DiffValue) that calculate the difference between Value and Value where SortNumer is = 1 (grouped by Slot and Period)

The problem is Slot and Period not necessarily have all same values for every SortNumber. In this case, I'd like to use 0 as default value and calculate the difference for every row.

I'm using `dplyr` and, when the data is consistent, works fine. Otherwise, I get the error : `"Column DiffValue must be length 1 (the group size), not 0"`

```
  dfAccess <-dfAccess %>%
  group_by(Slot, Period) %>%
  mutate(DiffValue = Value - Value[SortNumber == 1] )
```

Using this data, what I'd like to see is:

```
Slot     Period    SortNumber    Value    DiffValue
=========================================================
X1         1          1           9            0
X2         1          1           5            0
X3         1          1           7            0
X1         2          1           9            0
X3         2          1           5            0
X1         1          2           6           -3
X2         1          2           4           -1
X3         1          2           8            1
X2         2          2           2           -2 ("0" - 2)
X3         2          2           1           -4
```

Is that a way to do that?

EDIT: I modified parts of the original post because Sinh Nguyen identified a problem in the data but I'm still having problems to calculate the difference.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the error is in your actual data. At least one pair of `Slot+Period` doesn't have any `SortNumber==1`. From the error output, I guess that pair has only one record with `SortNumber!=1`

Comment: @SinhNguyen, you are totally right. SortNumber 1 has one row more than SortNumber 2.  I appologize for my fault. However, it brings a condition that I didn't expect to have.... if Slot and Period do not have the same values. Is there a way to calculate the difference assuming value 0 for the missing row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not fully sure about the nature of your dataset and what you want to achieve. But this would resolve the errors and for pair of `Slot+Period` that not have `SortNumber==1` it will automatically use `0(Zero)` as the default value.

```
# Sample data set with one pair of Slot+Period that doesn't have any SortNumber==1
dfAccess <- data.frame(Slot = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X1", "X2", "X3","X1", "X2", "X3","X1", "X2", "X3"), 
           Period = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2), 
           SortNumber = c(1, 1, 2, 1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2), 
           Value = c(9,5,7,9,1,5,6,4,8,10,2,1))

# Your command will generate an error
dfAccess <-dfAccess %>%
      group_by(Slot, Period) %>%
      mutate(DiffValue = Value - Value[SortNumber == 1] )
# ​Error: Column `DiffValue` must be length 2 (the group size) or one, not 0

# This command will only take 1st value of SortNumber==1 in any pair Slot+Number
dfAccess %>%
    group_by(Slot, Period) %>%
    mutate(DiffValue = Value - first(Value[SortNumber==1], default=0)) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am understanding correctly, but just as an exercise, I converted your dataframe to a wider format so it can be more easily viewed:

```r
df <- dfAccess %>%
  filter(SortNumber == 1) %>% 
  full_join(
    dfAccess %>% 
      filter(SortNumber == 2),
    by= c("Slot", "Period")
  ) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Value.x, Value.y), replace_na, 0) %>%    # impute missing values with zero
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    DiffValue = Value.y - Value.x
  )
```

`df` contains:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  Slot  Period SortNumber.x Value.x SortNumber.y Value.y DiffValue
  <fct>  <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1 X1         1            1       9            2       6        -3
2 X2         1            1       5            2       4        -1
3 X3         1            1       7            2       8         1
4 X1         2            1       9           NA       0        -9
5 X3         2            1       5            2       1        -4
6 X2         2           NA       0            2       2         2
```

Note rows 4 and 6, where one or the other `SortNumber` is missing.

That can be put in a format similar to the one you asked for (my code is ugly, but works):

```r
df2 <- df %>% 
  select(1:4) %>% 
  rename(
    SortNumber = 3,
    Value = 4
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    DiffValue = 0
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows(
    df %>% 
      select(-3, -4) %>% 
      rename(
        SortNumber = 3,
        Value = 4
      )
  )
```

And `df2` contains:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   Slot  Period SortNumber Value DiffValue
   <fct>  <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 X1         1          1     9         0
 2 X2         1          1     5         0
 3 X3         1          1     7         0
 4 X1         2          1     9         0
 5 X3         2          1     5         0
 6 X2         2         NA     0         0
 7 X1         1          2     6        -3
 8 X2         1          2     4        -1
 9 X3         1          2     8         1
10 X1         2         NA     0        -9
11 X3         2          2     1        -4
12 X2         2          2     2         2
```

If you don't want to impute on "SortNumber == 2", then the alternative will be:

```r
df3 <- dfAccess %>%
  filter(SortNumber == 1) %>% 
  full_join(
    dfAccess %>% 
      filter(SortNumber == 2),
    by= c("Slot", "Period")
  ) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Value.x), replace_na, 0) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    DiffValue = Value.y - Value.x
  ) %>% 
  select(1:4) %>% 
  rename(
    SortNumber = 3,
    Value = 4
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    DiffValue = 0
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows(
    df %>% 
      select(-3, -4) %>% 
      rename(
        SortNumber = 3,
        Value = 4
      )
  )
```

And `df3` will be:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   Slot  Period SortNumber Value DiffValue
   <fct>  <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 X1         1          1     9         0
 2 X2         1          1     5         0
 3 X3         1          1     7         0
 4 X1         2          1     9         0
 5 X3         2          1     5         0
 6 X2         2         NA     0         0
 7 X1         1          2     6        -3
 8 X2         1          2     4        -1
 9 X3         1          2     8         1
10 X1         2         NA    NA        NA
11 X3         2          2     1        -4
12 X2         2          2     2         2
```

HTH or at least gives you and idea on how to solve this problem